# Binding data to label with static text

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
```

when I call the DataBind() function, ID is displayed as follows:

```
14
```

but what if I want to display the ID like this:

```
ID: 14
```

this didn't work.

```
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='ID: ' + '<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Text='<%# "ID: " +Eval("ID").ToString() %>'
```

Comment: this gives me an error, saying:
'The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context'

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "ID: " +Eval("ID").ToString() %>' />
```

You cannot concatenate the values of attributes in XML.

You basically have XML like this:

```
<element attribute="ID" + "sometext"/>
```

which is not valid - instead you need to let the preprocessor change the output of the XML so that only the value of the attribute is modified.

Comment: this time the result looks like this in my label
`ID: <%# Bind("ID") %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "ID: " + Bind("ID") %>'   />
```

Or

```
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("ID: {0}", Bind("ID")) %>'   />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "ID: " +Eval("ID").ToString() %>' />
```